# Volley parsing Json response is null Android

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-volley

I am trying to parse JSON Object using volley but it is giving all the values as null

I am using GsonRequest custom class to parse using GSON library

```
public class GsonRequest < T > extends JsonRequest < T > {

    /** Charset for request. */
    private static final String PROTOCOL_CHARSET = "utf-8";

    /** Content type for request. */
    private static final String PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE = String.format("application/json; charset=%s", PROTOCOL_CHARSET);

    private final Gson mGson;
    //private final String mBody;
    private final Class < T > clazz;
    private final Listener < T > listener;
    private final Map < String,
    String > headers;
    private final String mBody;

    public GsonRequest(int method, String url, String body, Class < T > clazz, Map < String, String > headers, Response.Listener < T > listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, (body == null) ? null: body, listener, errorListener);
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.mBody = body;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.listener = listener;
        mGson = new Gson();
    }@Override
    public Map < String,
    String > getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return headers != null ? headers: super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response < T > parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(mGson.fromJson(json, clazz), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch(JsonSyntaxException e) {
            Log.e("JsonSyntaxException", " " + e);
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
}
```

I have created model class using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ below is my model class

```
public class ModelConnection {

    private List < Datum > data = new ArrayList < Datum > ();
    private Integer code;
    private Object message;
    private Map < String,
    Object > additionalProperties = new HashMap < String,
    Object > ();

    /**
     * 
     *  @return
     *  The data
     */
    public List < Datum > getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param data
     *     The Data
     */
    public void setData(List < Datum > data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The code
     */
    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param code
     *     The Code
     */
    public void setCode(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The message
     */
    public Object getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param message
     *     The Message
     */
    public void setMessage(Object message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Map < String,
    Object > getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    public class Datum {

        private Integer userID;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String title;
        private String organization;
        private String industry;
        private String location;
        private String profileSummary;
        private String imagePath;
        private List < Object > interests = new ArrayList < Object > ();
        private Map < String,
        Object > additionalProperties = new HashMap < String,
        Object > ();

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The userID
         */
        public Integer getUserID() {
            return userID;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param userID
         *     The UserID
         */
        public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
            this.userID = userID;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The firstName
         */
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param firstName
         *     The FirstName
         */
        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The lastName
         */
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param lastName
         *     The LastName
         */
        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The title
         */
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param title
         *     The Title
         */
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The organization
         */
        public String getOrganization() {
            return organization;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param organization
         *     The Organization
         */
        public void setOrganization(String organization) {
            this.organization = organization;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The industry
         */
        public String getIndustry() {
            return industry;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param industry
         *     The Industry
         */
        public void setIndustry(String industry) {
            this.industry = industry;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The location
         */
        public String getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param location
         *     The Location
         */
        public void setLocation(String location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The profileSummary
         */
        public String getProfileSummary() {
            return profileSummary;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param profileSummary
         *     The ProfileSummary
         */
        public void setProfileSummary(String profileSummary) {
            this.profileSummary = profileSummary;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The imagePath
         */
        public String getImagePath() {
            return imagePath;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param imagePath
         *     The ImagePath
         */
        public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
            this.imagePath = imagePath;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The interests
         */
        public List < Object > getInterests() {
            return interests;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param interests
         *     The Interests
         */
        public void setInterests(List < Object > interests) {
            this.interests = interests;
        }

        public Map < String,
        Object > getAdditionalProperties() {
            return this.additionalProperties;
        }

        public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
            this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
        }

    }

}
```

This is the response from rest client

```
{
  -"Data": [2]
  -0:  {
        "UserID": 124
        "FirstName": "Mixer"
        "LastName": "Development"
        "Title": "Flipdex Architect "
        "Organization": "CoStrategix"
        "Industry": "Software "
        "Location": "Bengaluru Area, India"
        "ProfileSummary": "Mixer#^*+~|Software engineer?????????? 123456789"@&$)(;:/-.,?!ASDFZgZhXjZkZlZXCVZbNZmQWERTYUIOZp[]{}#%^*+¥£€><~|\_.,?! "
        "ImagePath": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_tiUBxkxpFtDhAIKrczfJBnzj6FMhlWiAOiiJJAUpF8YTlJayP3DBA3Mp5NrycIrrczfJ48nymk-3-DwljKYwBKBKIk-8-DErYKYNylCgh5F24Rlu-3HVpLuuwAHKUDj3c1VURiTsxsU"
        "Interests": [0]
      }

  -1: {
        "UserID": 153
        "FirstName": "Mixer"
        "LastName": "Android"
        "Title": "Assistant Manager at CoStrategix"
        "Organization": "CoStrategix"
        "Industry": "Software"
        "Location": "Bengaluru Area, India"
        "ProfileSummary": "We have worked with over 35+ product companies and bring the critical thinking and technology expertise to launching your product. We have l"
        "ImagePath": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_0EwKKqh9nkV0X1t3pmPYj6B9ncH0T_TTJy0K9h29KnTYT1u8zElOR_C9q3zGb1gDJyjY4_SnOQUOGFf8zJmuZhhsUQUxGFHTzJmPP3zBKbm1HA1jMe4j1vRQR1T7wFxKysoyq1W3CaQ"
        "Interests": [0]
      }

   "Code": 1
   "Message": null
}
```

finally this is the way I am calling the api

```
GsonRequest request = new GsonRequest(Request.Method.GET, newConnectionAPI,null, ModelConnection.class, getHeaders(),
            new Response.Listener<ModelConnection>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(ModelConnection response) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.networkResponseSuccessful(response);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("volley error", "" + error);
        }
    });
    request.setTag(tag);
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(request);
```

when I debug I get all the values as null

Can anyone please help me out

Comment: it dosent print anything, if I debug the response is showing all values null

Comment: check for response code you are getting...

Comment: first test run the url and the data you are sending in postman. then if it is getting the result you want ? if yes then check for error in your code. is your postman response is successful ?

Comment: Yes response is coming properly if I run the url.I have posted the answer for  the problem below.

Answer (score 1):

Thought of answering my own question, may be someone can get help through this...

I created my Model class using jsonschema2pojo where I had to select JSON along with GSON(Which I forgot to select).

you can see the difference if you compare the Model classes posted above and below

```
public class ModelConnection {

    @SerializedName("Data")@Expose
    private List < Datum > data = new ArrayList < Datum > ();@SerializedName("Code")@Expose
    private Integer code;@SerializedName("Message")@Expose
    private Object message;

    private Map < String,
    Object > additionalProperties = new HashMap < String,
    Object > ();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The data
     */
    public List < Datum > getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param data
     *     The Data
     */
    public void setData(List < Datum > data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The code
     */
    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param code
     *     The Code
     */
    public void setCode(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The message
     */
    public Object getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param message
     *     The Message
     */
    public void setMessage(Object message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Map < String,
    Object > getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    public class Datum implements Serializable {

        @SerializedName("UserId")@Expose
        private Integer userID;@SerializedName("FirstName")@Expose
        private String firstName;@SerializedName("LastName")@Expose
        private String lastName;@SerializedName("Title")@Expose
        private String title;@SerializedName("Organization")@Expose
        private String organization;@SerializedName("Industry")@Expose
        private String industry;@SerializedName("Location")@Expose
        private String location;@SerializedName("ProfileSummary")@Expose
        private String profileSummary;@SerializedName("ImagePath")@Expose
        private String imagePath;@SerializedName("Interests")@Expose
        private ArrayList < Interest > interest = new ArrayList < Interest > ();

        private Map < String,
        Object > additionalProperties = new HashMap < String,
        Object > ();

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The userID
         */
        public Integer getUserID() {
            return userID;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param userID
         *     The UserID
         */
        public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
            this.userID = userID;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The firstName
         */
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param firstName
         *     The FirstName
         */
        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The lastName
         */
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param lastName
         *     The LastName
         */
        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The title
         */
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param title
         *     The Title
         */
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The organization
         */
        public String getOrganization() {
            return organization;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param organization
         *     The Organization
         */
        public void setOrganization(String organization) {
            this.organization = organization;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The industry
         */
        public String getIndustry() {
            return industry;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param industry
         *     The Industry
         */
        public void setIndustry(String industry) {
            this.industry = industry;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The location
         */
        public String getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param location
         *     The Location
         */
        public void setLocation(String location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The profileSummary
         */
        public String getProfileSummary() {
            return profileSummary;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param profileSummary
         *     The ProfileSummary
         */
        public void setProfileSummary(String profileSummary) {
            this.profileSummary = profileSummary;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The imagePath
         */
        public String getImagePath() {
            return imagePath;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param imagePath
         *     The ImagePath
         */
        public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
            this.imagePath = imagePath;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         *     The interests
         */
        public ArrayList < Interest > getInterest() {
            return interest;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param interests
         *     The Interests
         */
        public void setInterest(ArrayList < Interest > interests) {
            this.interest = interests;
        }

        public Map < String,
        Object > getAdditionalProperties() {
            return this.additionalProperties;
        }

        public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
            this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
        }

    }
    public class Interest {

        @SerializedName("Name")@Expose
        private String name;

        /**
         *
         * @return
         * The name
         */
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param name
         * The Name
         */
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

}
```

May be because the objects were not properly serialized so GSON was unable to parse the JSON String properly.

Others advice over the above assumption is most welcome.